# Which database for savings sets of variables with various types?

Tags: database-design, architecture, microservices

I want to design a microservice. The goal is to save and serve sets of variables :

1 set is composed of several variables :

- height : `Float`
- name : `String`
- birthDate : `Date`
- ...

Every set has a predefined list of variables : (height, name, birthDate) with different types, always the same list. BUT, the list can change sometimes and we dont want to write new code then build then deploy it every time we do that. Ideally this list will be also stored in the database.

Also, one set must have a reference to an object which is stored outsilde the microservice. Let's say a set is linked to one `User`, so we have to keep a user identifier somewhere.

The question is : I know SQL databases and I have understood that they are not very suited for this kind of problem (it is not impossible, just ugly). So what other solution do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the thing you're looking for is a [schemaless database](http://martinfowler.com/articles/schemaless/):

On the concrete products out there - choose an established one that suits your needs. Some examples:

- MongoDB
- CouchDB
- (many others available - just google for it!)

**Possible solution for your example:**

The json you may want to store could look like this:

```
{
  "set_id":"someid",
  "owner":"usrid",
  "properties":
    {
      "height":2.5,
      "name":"somename",
      "birtDate":date,
      ...
    }
}
```

NOW, depending on what you'll need to do with the data in your application logic, you'll have to map the properties to something your language/program can handle you try to hande these Key/Values generic, i.e. not enforce any schema upon them - that is if that's feasable!

Comment: That is what I suspected. Nevertheless I was hoping for an exemple or any advise about the design I could make.

Comment: you might need to provide some more info as to your usecase if you need more details!

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems VERY flexible and I am not shure this will suits me, but thanks for your answer.